# Design a multi-process daemon

Tags: python, linux, daemon, python-daemon

I am writing a web application in Python (Django) that will execute tasks/process on the side, typically network scans. I would like the user to be able to terminate a scan, view its status or results in real-time.

I thought one of the best ways to do this is to have a job manager daemon that is a stand alone process, that:

1. Accepts new jobs via a TCP connection.
2. Accepts user-commands, typically to terminate or restart a process.
3. Reports on the status of a job.

I am struggling with the structure of this code. I am thinking that a TCP port on the daemon process will accept new jobs. It will then create an os.fork(), which itself will create an os.fork(). The second fork will perform an os.execv() for nmap. The first os.fork() will monitor the second fork (how?) and when it completes, it will report back to the master daemon that it has ended. The first fork must also be able to terminate the second child process.

How does that sound? Are there any structures of this already having been done? I would hate to re-create the wheel.

Finally, how would the child process know that the second child, the one running the os.execv() has terminated? Or whether its still running? I would hate to continuously poll a list of processes.

And as I've said, this must be done in Python.

Comment: you basically just described celery ...

Comment: I described celery? I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Celery is a python distributed task runner http://www.celeryproject.org/. That said, you did not, in fact, describe celery, you basically described a standard, run-of-the-mill, network daemon. It is possible to do what you ask for in python, but since you specifically said that you do not want to reinvent the wheel, I suggest you look at socketserver module included in python standard library https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a fork-based approach. This approach is "wrong", but it works and fulfills my needs.
https://gist.github.com/FarhansCode/a0f27469142b6afaa6c2